# What are the steps to select collect Oracle EBS Business Event for Order and Line Update

Tags: oracle-soa

This is about Oracle EBS and Oracle SOA.

I am trying to write a Oracle SOA composite application that uses Oracle EBS Business Event(s).  The application must detect order and order line creation or change and then transport the order or line information from EBS to a set of MSSQL database tables.  There are certain restrictions to how we can solve this puzzle.

The restrictions of this puzzle are:

- Oracle EBS (11) Business Event must be used (not AQ directly, or Concurrent programs directly)
- Oracle SOA Suite (11.1.1.7) and Application Adapter must be used (as to other adapters)
- MSSQL database tables are the destination (so I am choosing to use Database Adapter)
- SOA composite application must be instantiated upon order (OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL) or line (OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL) creation or change not specific to their state or fields

The challenge I have right now is finding the correct business event or small set of correct Business Events from the predefined Business Event(s) that satisfy the last criteria.

Does anyone have the answer or hint to solve this puzzle?

Thanks

Comment: My team learned that using "Processing Constraint" EBS windows to configure the detection criteria on Order Headers and Lines is required.  Once that is configured, oracle.apps.ont.oi.xml_int.status business event in SOA.  But it seems there are some other configurations somewhere in EBS or WLS to make the event get SOA Apps Adapter instantiate.  We don't know what that is yet (DB and Apps adapter and their JNDI names are already configured correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We selected oracle.apps.ont.oi.xml_int.status as the business event to use.

Good reference of how to set that up

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2337912?tstart=0

After that in JDeveloper/SOA Composite Application, create Oracle Application adapter, and then wire that to a BEPL component.  In BPEL component, extract "HEADER_ID" in PARAMTER_LIST_ITEM element.